# Ruby: Object.to_a replacement

Tags: ruby

I need to convert a passed in argument (single object or collection) to an Array. I don't know what the argument is. If it is an Array already, I want to leave it, otherwise create a one-element array from it. I'm looking to **allow both `method(:objs => obj)` and `method(:objs => [obj1, obj2])`**

This seems to be the best way (Array#to_a returns self):

```
arg = arg.to_a
```

But the ruby docs say **`Object#to_a` will soon be obsolete**. Is there convenient replacement?

Anything more succinct than this?

```
arg = arg.respond_to?(:to_a) ? arg.to_a : [arg]
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use the method [Kernel#Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005989):

```
Array([1,2,3]) #=> [1, 2, 3]
Array(123) #=> [123]
```

Yes it may look like a class at first but this is actually a method that starts with a capital letter.

Comment: Perfect!  Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: A couple things to keep in mind, though: 1) If you pass a hash to Array() you'll get hash.to_a, not [hash]. 2) If you pass nil to Array() you'll get [], not [nil].

Comment: Ruby is so cool. Everything is an object. I mean, sometimes. Well, Kernel, that's an object, and it's also got some objecty methods on it too, with capital letters! So what does `Kernel.Array` do anyway? Oh yeah, it calls the `to_ary` method on the object. If that doesn't work, it puts your parameter into a single-element array. Tricky!

Comment: No wait, that was wrong. Sorry, this is so clear in the docs. It calls `to_a`... Oh, here it is from 1.9 "Returns arg as an Array. First tries to call arg.to_ary, then arg.to_a." WTF?????

Comment: Just to be clear, both nil.to_a and Array(nil) return an empty array.

Answer (score 9):

Wow, someone just necromanced a really old thread. :-O But since I don't see it included yet, I'll add one more way for completeness' sake:

```
arg = [*arg]
```

This will splat the argument if it already is an array (thus removing one level of nesting) or create a one-argument array otherwise:

```
arg = [1,2,3]
[*arg] #=> [1, 2, 3]
arg = 1
[*arg] #=> [1]
```

Comment: as allways you're brilliant!

Comment: In fact, it returns the same result as `Array()`. For example: `[*nil]` => `[]`, `[*{a: 'a', b: 'b'}]` => `[[:a, "a"], [:b, "b"]]`

Answer (score 2):

It seems only [`Object.to_a`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Object.html#M000628) is deprecated, removing a default `to_a` and forcing each class to define its own (e.g., [`Hash.to_a`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Hash.html#M000153)).

```
self.to_a       #=> -:1: warning: default `to_a' will be obsolete
"hello".to_a    #=> ["hello"]
Time.new.to_a   #=> [39, 54, 8, 9, 4, 2003, 3, 99, true, "CDT"]

h = { "c" => 300, "a" => 100, "d" => 400, "c" => 300  }
h.to_a   #=> [["a", 100], ["c", 300], ["d", 400]]
```

If your argument is an instance of `Object`, try:

```
Hash.new(obj).to_a
```

---

@Daniel [comment to Ollivier]: *The point is that I don't know what the argument is. If it is an array already, I want to leave it, otherwise create a one-element array.*

If that's the case, try:

```
obj = [obj] if !obj.is_a?(Array)
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, and Hash.new(obj).to_a always returns [].

Comment: obj = [obj] unless obj.is_a?(Array) might be easier to read.. unless you don't like 'unless' of course!

Comment: Nope. Just never used it before. Still a bit green with Ruby. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can take the duck typing aproach if that suits the problem better, make a list of all the methods you need, and check if the object already have them, if not, make it an array:

```
[:[], :each, :etc...].all? { |m| obj.respond_to? m } ? obj : [obj]
```

The advantage is that you give the object a chance to implement it's own semantics for indexed access.

Answer (score 2):

I do this a lot, and always use:

```
arg = [arg] unless arg.is_a?(Array)
```

Though if you know you're never passing in arrays as individual arguments you can also do:

```
arg = [arg].flatten
```

Comment: this is the best and most explicit solution, no weird corner cases with hashes or nil.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this helps, but what I often need is not that the arg be an array, but that the arg responds to each.

```
arg = [arg] unless arg.respond_to? :each
```

Comment: Lots of things that aren't an array respond to `each`.

Answer (score 0):

What about Array.new(1, arg)?

Comment: The point is that I don't know what the argument is.  If it is an array already, I want to leave it, otherwise create a one-element array.