# Convert Ruby hash into array without calling `Hash#to_a`

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, casting

The [Savon gem](http://savonrb.com/) I am using is giving me back a single object or an array, and I have no way to know which it will be until the SOAP response comes back.

For convenience I would like to have a `nil` response converted to `[]`, a single response converted to `[obj]` and an array stay as an array. This can easily be done with [`Kernel#Array`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385912/ruby-object-to-a-replacement), thus:

```
> Array nil
=> [] 
> Array 1
=> [1] 
> Array [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

However, because `Kernel#Array` calls `to_a`, it fails for [`Hash` which overrides `to_a`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-to_a):

```
> Array({a: 1})
=> [[:a, 1]]
> Array([{a: 1}, {b: 2}])
=> [{:a=>1}, {:b=>2}]
```

On line 2 above I would like to see `[{:a=>1}]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>> [nil].compact.flatten(1)
=> []
>> [1].compact.flatten(1)
=> [1]
>> [{a: 1, b: 2}].compact.flatten(1)
=> [{:a=>1, :b=>2}]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ActiveSupport, you can do the following:

```
> Array.wrap({a: 1})
=> [{:a, 1}]
> Array.wrap([{a: 1}, {b: 2}])
=> [{:a=>1}, {:b=>2}]
```

Comment: Accepted for now, unless someone can come up with an equally elegant solution that doesn't require ActiveSupport.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I am able to bypass `Hash#to_a` with my own `straight_to_a` method:

```
def straight_to_a(o)
  o.kind_of?(Array) ? o : [o].compact
end
```

Thus:

```
> straight_to_a nil
=> [] 
> straight_to_a 1
=> [1] 
> straight_to_a( {a: 1} )
=> [{:a=>1}]
```

I'm hoping there's an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

Another poster suggested the use of Active Support. If you don't want to add an extra dependency to your project for just one method, here is the source code for Active Support's `Array.wrap`:

```
class Array
  def self.wrap(object)
    if object.nil?
      []
    elsif object.respond_to?(:to_ary)
      object.to_ary || [object]
    else
      [object]
    end
  end
end
```

You could easily add this code to your own `utilities.rb` or `core_extensions.rb` file and include that in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems ok, perhaps you can try something based on `flatten`, like

```
def straight_to_a *ary
  ary.flatten(1)
end
```