# Ruby - elegantly convert variable to an array if not an array already

Tags: ruby, arrays

Given an array, a single element, or nil, obtain an array - the latter two being a single element array and an empty array respectively.

I mistakenly figured Ruby would work this way:

```
[1,2,3].to_a  #= [1,2,3]     # Already an array, so no change
1.to_a        #= [1]         # Creates an array and adds element
nil.to_a      #= []          # Creates empty array
```

But what you really get is:

```
[1,2,3].to_a  #= [1,2,3]         # Hooray
1.to_a        #= NoMethodError   # Do not want
nil.to_a      #= []              # Hooray
```

So to solve this, I either need to use another method, or I could meta program by modifying the to_a method of all classes I intend to use - which is not an option for me.

So a Method it is:

```
result = nums.class == "Array".constantize ? nums : (nums.class == "NilClass".constantize ? [] : ([]<<nums))
```

The problem is that it is a bit of a mess. Is there an elegant way of doing this? (I would be amazed if this is the Ruby-ish way to solve this problem)

---

### What applications does this have? Why even convert to an array?

In Rails' ActiveRecord, calling say, `user.posts` will either return an array of posts, a single post, or nil. When writing methods which work on the results of this, it is easiest to assume that the method will take an array, which may have zero, one, or many elements. Example method:

```
current_user.posts.inject(true) {|result, element| result and (element.some_boolean_condition)}
```

Comment: `user.posts` should never return a single post. At least, I never seen it.

Comment: i think in your first two code blocks you mean `==` instead of `=`, right?

Comment: Possible udplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385912/ruby-object-to-a-replacement

Comment: Btw, `[1,2,3].to_a` does **not** return `[[1,2,3]]`! It returns `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: Thanks paddle, will update question... *facepalms at self*

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. I was looking through the source for ActiveSupport#wrap and wondering what ppl used it for. Nice to see this question and @elado's answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby: Object.to\_a replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385912/ruby-object-to-a-replacement)

Answer (score 175, accepted):

`[*foo]` or `Array(foo)` will work most of the time, but for some cases like a hash, it messes it up.

```
Array([1, 2, 3])    # => [1, 2, 3]
Array(1)            # => [1]
Array(nil)          # => []
Array({a: 1, b: 2}) # => [[:a, 1], [:b, 2]]

[*[1, 2, 3]]    # => [1, 2, 3]
[*1]            # => [1]
[*nil]          # => []
[*{a: 1, b: 2}] # => [[:a, 1], [:b, 2]]
```

The only way I can think of that works even for a hash is to define a method.

```
class Object; def ensure_array; [self] end end
class Array; def ensure_array; to_a end end
class NilClass; def ensure_array; to_a end end

[1, 2, 3].ensure_array    # => [1, 2, 3]
1.ensure_array            # => [1]
nil.ensure_array          # => []
{a: 1, b: 2}.ensure_array # => [{a: 1, b: 2}]
```

Comment: instead of `ensure_array`, extend `to_a`

Comment: @screenmutt That would affect methods that rely on the original use of `to_a`. For instance, `{a: 1, b: 2}.each ...` would work differently.

Comment: Right! I forgot about the new `to_a` methods since 1.8.7

Comment: Another option maybe [o].flatten(1)

Comment: @rhernando That doesn't work for `o = [[1, 2, 3]]`. It removes an array layer.

Comment: Here 'o' in an Array of one element (another array), so you will get the same Array (with the same element): [o].flatten(1)  => [[1, 2, 3]]

Comment: @rhernando That is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @sawa  o.ensure_array == [o].flatten(1), so both approaches would have the same problem

Comment: @rhernando No it's not. .

Comment: Can you explain this syntax? In many years of Ruby i had never come across this type of invocation. What do parentheses on a class name do? I can't find this in docs.

Comment: @mastaBlasta Array(arg) tries to create a new array by calling to_ary, then to_a on the argument. This is documented in official ruby docs. I learned about it from Avdi's "Confident Ruby" book.

Comment: @mambo At some point after i had posted my question I did find the answer. The hard part was that it has nothing to do with Array class but it's a method on Kernel module. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-Array

Answer (score 148):

With ActiveSupport (Rails): `Array.wrap`

```
Array.wrap([1, 2, 3])     # => [1, 2, 3]
Array.wrap(1)             # => [1]
Array.wrap(nil)           # => []
Array.wrap({a: 1, b: 2})  # => [{:a=>1, :b=>2}]
```

If you are not using Rails, you can define your own method similar to [the rails source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/wrap.rb).

```
class Array
  def self.wrap(object)
    if object.nil?
      []
    elsif object.respond_to?(:to_ary)
      object.to_ary || [object]
    else
      [object]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `class Array; singleton_class.send(:alias_method, :hug, :wrap); end` for extra cuteness.

Answer (score 21):

The simplest solution is to use `[foo].flatten(1)`. Unlike other proposed solutions, it will work well for (nested) arrays, hashes and `nil`:

```
def wrap(foo)
  [foo].flatten(1)
end

wrap([1,2,3])         #= [1,2,3]
wrap([[1,2],[3,4]])   #= [[1,2],[3,4]]
wrap(1)               #= [1]
wrap(nil)             #= [nil]
wrap({key: 'value'})  #= [{key: 'value'}]
```

Comment: unfortunately this one has serious performance issue compared to other approaches. `Kernel#Array` i.e. `Array()` is the fastest of them all. Ruby 2.5.1 comparison: 

Array():        7936825.7 i/s.
Array.wrap:  4199036.2 i/s - 1.89x  slower.
wrap:           644030.4 i/s - 12.32x  slower

Answer (score 20):

`Array(whatever)` should do the trick

```
Array([1,2,3]) # [1,2,3]
Array(nil) # []
Array(1337)   # [1337]
```

Comment: won't work for Hash. Array({a: 1, b: 2}) will be [[:a, 1], [:b, 2]]

Answer (score 13):

## ActiveSupport (Rails)

ActiveSupport has a pretty nice method for this. It's loaded with Rails, so defiantly the nicest way to do this:

```
Array.wrap([1, 2, 3]) #=> [1, 2, 3]
Array.wrap(nil) #=> nil
```

## Splat (Ruby 1.9+)

The splat operator (`*`) un-arrays an array, if it can:

```
*[1,2,3] #=> 1, 2, 3 (notice how this DOES not have braces)
```

Of course, without an array, it does weird things, and the objects you "splat" need to be put in arrays. It's somewhat weird, but it means:

```
[*[1,2,3]] #=> [1, 2, 3]
[*5] #=> [5]
[*nil] #=> []
[*{meh: "meh"}] #=> [[:meh, "meh"], [:meh2, "lol"]]
```

If you don't have ActiveSupport, you can define the method:

```
class Array
    def self.wrap(object)
        [*object]
    end
end

Array.wrap([1, 2, 3]) #=> [1, 2, 3]
Array.wrap(nil) #=> nil
```

Although, if you plan on having large arrays, and less non-array things, you might want to change it - the above method is slow with large arrays, and can even cause your Stack to Overflow (omg so meta). Anyways, you might want to do this instead:

```
class Array
    def self.wrap(object)
        object.is_a? Array ? object : [*object]
    end
end

Array.wrap([1, 2, 3]) #=> [1, 2, 3]
Array.wrap(nil) #=> [nil]
```

I also have some [benchmarks](https://gist.github.com/benaubin/84aebfdf4f5cbda6260c) with and without the teneray operator.

Comment: Won't work for big arrays. `SystemStackError: stack level too deep` for 1M elements (ruby 2.2.3).

Comment: @denis.peplin seems like you got a StackOverflow error :D - honestly, I'm not sure what happened. Sorry.

Comment: I recently tried `Hash#values_at` with 1M arguments (using `splat`), and it throws the same error.

Comment: @denis.peplin Does it work with `object.is_a? Array ? object : [*object]`?

Comment: `Array.wrap(nil)` returns `[]` not `nil` :/

Answer (score 7):

How about

```
[].push(anything).flatten
```

Comment: Yeah I think I ended up using [anything].flatten in my case... but for the general case this will also flatten any nested array structures

Comment: `[].push(anything).flatten(1)` would work! It does not flatten nested arrays!

Answer (score 2):

With the risk of stating the obvious, and knowing that this isn't the most tasty syntactic sugar ever seen on the planet and surrounding areas, this code seems to do exactly what you describe:

```
foo = foo.is_a?(Array) ? foo : foo.nil? ? [] : [foo]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can overwrite the array method of Object

```
class Object
    def to_a
        [self]
    end
end
```

everything inherits Object, therefore to_a will now be defined for everything under the sun

Comment: blasphemous monkey patching! Repent ye!

Answer (score 1):

I've gone through all the answers and mostly don't work in ruby 2+

But elado has the most elegant solution i.e

> With ActiveSupport (Rails): Array.wrap
>
> Array.wrap([1, 2, 3])     # => [1, 2, 3]
>
> Array.wrap(1)             # => [1]
>
> Array.wrap(nil)           # => []
>
> Array.wrap({a: 1, b: 2})  # => [{:a=>1, :b=>2}]

Sadly but this also doesn't work for ruby 2+ as you will get an error

```
undefined method `wrap' for Array:Class
```

So in order to fix that you need to require.

> require 'active_support/deprecation'
>
> require 'active_support/core_ext/array/wrap'

Answer (score 0):

Since the method `#to_a` already exists for the two main problematic classes (`Nil` and `Hash`), just define a method for the rest by extending `Object`:

```
class Object
    def to_a
        [self]
    end
end
```

and then you can easily call that method on any object:

```
"Hello world".to_a
# => ["Hello world"]
123.to_a
# => [123]
{a:1, b:2}.to_a
# => [[:a, 1], [:b, 2]] 
nil.to_a
# => []
```

Comment: I really think monkey patching a core Ruby class, especially object, is to be avoided. I'll give ActiveSupport a pass though so consider me a hypocrite. The solutions above by @sawa are much more viable than this.