# How to not repeat code when looping over a data structure where a key's value can be a hash or multi-item array?

Tags: ruby

I have a complex data structure that looks as follows:

```
ds1 =
{
  'item1' =>
  {
    'value' => '1024',
    'flavor' => %w(s m l xl),
    'platform_version' => %w(7),
  },
  'item2' =>
  [{
    'value' => '2000000',
    'flavor' => %w(l xl),
    'platform_version' => %w(7),
  },
  {
    'value' => '1000000',
    'flavor' => %w(s m),
    'platform_version' => %w(6),
  },],
}
```

I'm currently looping over this as follows:

```
ds1.each do |name, obj|
  if obj.is_a?(Array)
    # Found that the data structure has multiple scenarios for the same key and need to loop over each element
    obj.each do |sub_obj|
      next unless flavor_check?(sub_obj, s_lit, 'flavor') # calls flavor_check? function
      obj_func(name, sub_obj) # call a function here
    end
  else
    # hash only has one element so treat normally, no need for another loop
    next unless flavor_check?(sub_obj, s_lit, 'flavor') # calls flavor_check? function
    obj_func(name, sub_obj) # call a function here
  end
end
```

Sometimes I have much more code that I need to execute and having to repeat it twice depending on whether the "obj" is an array or not just makes my code look busy/ugly.  Is there a more elegant way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just wrap it in an array all the time:

```
ds1.each do |name, obj|
  [obj].flatten(1).each do |sub_obj|
    next unless flavor_check?(sub_obj, s_lit, 'flavor') # calls flavor_check? function
    obj_func(name, sub_obj) # call a function here
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried this before but since "obj" is a hash, I think I am running into something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358717/ruby-elegantly-convert-variable-to-an-array-if-not-an-array-already

Comment: @sconicelli You are right. I wasn't aware of this edge case. I changed my answer to that suggested version from the other question which I liked best.

Comment: Thanks!  made sense for me to just extend Array like rails does... not sure why Ruby itself doesn't add this feature.  Problem solved though...

Comment: You can replace `[obj].flatten(1)` with `Array(obj)` or `[*obj]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Unfortunately, `Array(obj)`  or `[*obj]` doesn't work in this example, because here the single element would be a hash and the expected the response would be an array with one hash inside. But instead, an array of arrays is returned. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18358717/2483313

Comment: I didn't know that! (I guess that's obvious.) I'll leave my comment for its educational value, unless you prefer that I remove it.

Comment: Is `(1)` needed?

Comment: Yes `(1)` is needed to cover another edge case: When obj is already a nested array,  `flatten` (without the parameter) would remove the nesting.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Seems like we both learned the same things and asked the same questions today while thinking about an answer.  Please leave your comment!

Comment: Re `(1)`, I was going by the nesting in the example, but you have a good point--better to cover the general case.